# bash terminal on kubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have noticed that on my Kubuntu installation, the terminal is Konsole. How do I set it to use bash  instead?

Comment: Konsole is just a terminal emulator.. Bash is the default shell on Ubuntu variants. Try `echo $SHELL` to confirm.

Comment: thank - so how do I launch bash?

Comment: how do I set my terminal to not be konsole? like on a mac it uses bash? I understand konsole is an emulator - but I dont want to use it.

Comment: @Hello-World On a Mac you (usually) use ‘Terminal’, which is a [terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) just like Konsole (and many others). The [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) within it has little or nothing to do with the emulator; you can use Terminal and KSH, or Konsole and ZSH, and so on. If you don't want to use an emulator (why wouldn't you?) you're left with using a TTY (or similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually using a bash terminal. Konsole is a kind of emulator. I am quoting an answer from [unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111559/what-is-the-different-bash-per-terminal-session-for-konsole) site, when you can find more info about the type of shell you are using.

> /etc/passwd defines the default shell for the user, of which bash is just the most common option. Alternatives to bash are zsh, ksh, csh etc. You can google each of them to find out more about them. The default shell is the program that will be run inside of Konsole, which essentially can work with any shell or terminal program for that matter.

(P.S /bin/sh is bash (Bourne Again SHell) terminal.)

Comment: What do you mean by "/bin/sh is bash"? `/bin/sh` is (usually) the [Bourne Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) or a symlink to *some* other shell that can *emluate* the Bourne Shell.

Comment: @Biffen I just try to explain that the /bin/sh at the end of the lines of /etc/passwd file indicates that this user is using a Bash-type shell. And modern linux system, which is the case of Kubuntu, link /bin/sh to a Bourne Againe SHell rather than the classic, old Bourne shell, as it offers more capabilities.

Comment: If you want Bash as your shell you should put `/bin/bash` in `/etc/passwd`. `/bin/sh` *may* be a symlink to Bash, but it's by no means guaranteed to be, or to be in the future.

Comment: @Biffen once again, I try to explain to an obviously newcomer to linux that he is currently using Bash and how he can check this out. Yes you are right, yes it is a symlink to bash, and yes it is not explicitly stated that someone using bash by the /bin/sh link. Do you believe that was the point of the question, or the piece of information you provide is useful to him? I did not tried to show off my Unix capabilities , I tried to give a short and simple answer. That's it.

Comment: I (think I) get what you're saying. But saying that "/bin/sh is bash" is simply *not true*, and I thought it should be pointed out. And yes, I *do* think what I said was useful to them and possibly to others.